# Jquery for submit form button is not working

Tags: html, jquery

I am writing a jquery to submit the form in case its valid but its not working. I am using Bootstrap form and using Browser Default for validation.

Here is my jquery code

```
var form = $("#contactForm");
 $(document).on("click", "#submit-btn", function(){
  if(form.valid()){
    alert("Form Submitted Successfully")
  }
 })
});
```

Here is my form

```
<form class="row contact-form shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="width:auto; margin-left: 0.4%;" name="form" id="contactForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12 mb-sm-3">
      <label for="name" class="form-label"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
      <label for="email" class="form-label"></label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter You Email" required />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      <label for="subject" class="form-label"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject Of your Inquiry" required />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      <label for="message" class="form-label"></label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this ?

Comment: Which plugin are you using for validation?

Comment: What does Browser Default for validation mean? Do you mean the jQuery validation plugin? What error do you see in the console?

Comment: 1) your check is on button click, it needs to be on form submit as there's other ways to submit a form than click a button
2) you don't *cancel* the button click, so it carries on with the submit regardless: add `return false` (or preventDefault)
3) you don't submit the form if valid - use `$("form")[0].submit()` to submit using js or make an ajax call.

Comment: *[it's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)* - please be specific - is your `alert` working?  is the form submitting anyway (it will based on the code provided)?  What's it doing / not doing that you want it to do / not do?

Comment: Could be where your js code is - maybe you've set `var form=` outside doc.ready and before the form exists on the page - make sure `form.length === 1` or move your code to the bottom of the html.

Comment: You're missing a `"` just before your button - probably a copy-to-question-issue, but maybe your browser is being difficult?

Comment: @prettyInPink  browser default as mentioned in bootstrap 5 , is validated by browser itself such as if input is empty or email is not of correct format. I am not using any other plugin . only bootstrap 5 form. You can seen browser default validation here in this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/

Comment: Check your console for errors:  *form.valid() is not a function* - given your code and html:  https://jsfiddle.net/za5wt09x/

Comment: You're probably looking for `if (form[0].valid)` if you're using HTML 5 validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation  (https://jsfiddle.net/za5wt09x/1/) `$("form").valid()` is for [jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

Comment: i tried if (form[0].valid) but it is still not working.  I checked on my side, the issue is with the condition itself. I think i need to write a seperate condition if these inputs are not empty and try it again